# Progress Web Application .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I want to create Survey web app, i want to know where does the data get saved when user submit the data in offline mode, how does the offline saved data get sync in database once user comes online, also can we call the same web app in android native app?

Thanks
Shubham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short when a user submits their data your app will always store it to web storage (indexedDB for example) first. From here your app would attempt to Sync the content with the online server.

If this is successful you clear the synced changes.

If not your app can display the number of unsynced changes and attempt to resync at a point in the future (could be user interaction, a timer or online status change event)